# Mirroring - server network address cannot be reached or does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have read a number of articles on how to configure mirroring on SQL Server 2012. I went through the steps and everything worked until hitting the final step, which didn't work.

When I run this on the Principal:

> ALTER DATABASE MyDBName SET PARTNER = 'TCP://1.2.3.4:5022';

I get this error:

> The server network address "TCP://1.2.3.4:5022" can not be
>   reached or does not exist.

When I run the counterpart ALTER statement shown above, but on the Mirror, it works fine.

I have tried all the steps in this [troubleshooting article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/11/the-server-network-address-tcpsqlserver5023-can-not-be-reached-or-does-not-exist-check-the-network-address-name-and-that-the-ports-for-the-local-and-remote-endpoints-are-operational-microso/).

Important points:

1. The Primary and Mirror servers are in different datacenters, not on the same network at all. Not connected by VPN. Completely untrusted by each other.
2. I can connect to the Mirror via SSMS on the Primary and run queries. And vice versa.
3. I configured certificates on each server to establish the trust relationship. Everything worked during the setup and config, no errors.
4. I configured the endpoints on both servers and verified they're active/enabled.
5. I opened port 5022 on both servers by configuring incoming and outgoing windows firewall rules. I can telnet to the Mirror from the Principal and vice versa - ports appear open, no problems.
6. In the troubleshooting guide mentioned above, I tried steps 1-6. I didn't try 7, deleting the endpoints and re-creating, because they look perfectly valid and active to me.

Looking for some ideas on this one.

Comment: Did you try to disable Windows Firewall on both machines and then try? I've had a couple of times that, although I had (IMHO correct) rules configured for MSSQL, the firewall somehow blocked in or outgoing connections. Doing this test would at least allow you to either know if its the firewall or not so you can rule that out.

Comment: @deroby: I just tried turning the firewall completely off on both servers. No difference. Same error.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder: Did you resolve this issue. I know this is an old post. But now I have run into a similar one, and can't find a solution. What was your solution if you have resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can telnet that port from the principal machine everything is fine with TCP/IP and firewall settings.

I can remember that I had a similar issue in the past. Unfortunatly I dont remember the exact solution but it was related to security/authentication of the endpoints and the SQL Server service account not having enough permission on the mirror machine. Unfortunatly the error message is pretty misleading in this case. Script the endpoints and verify their settings, SSMS has no UI for that.
Another thing that you could check is that you have the possibility to also connect to port 5022 from the mirror to the principal machine. You will get the same error message if the connection is not possible from both instances.

Sorry that I cant provide you a proper solution, but maybe that points you to the right direction.

Comment: I can connect from mirror to principal 5022. I can telnet to the port from each machine. What permissions should I grant SQL Server service?

Comment: Per default only users having sysadmin role on the local machine are able to connect to Endpoints. In my case I was on the same domain, but that is not applicable to your scenario. You have to make sure the Endpoint is created specifying your certificate as authorisation, a login is created and assigned to that certificate and finally the login is granted permission to that Endpoint. [see this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2011/08/24/setting-up-database-mirroring-with-certificates.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are quite non-informative error messages in MS SQL. The problem might be an authorization issue and the server still will be saying "network address can not be reached".

Considering "servers are in different datacenters", how the authentication is performed? A MSSQL service (on server1) itself must be runned as a valid db user (on server2, and vice versa) in order to make the mirroring work.

Comment: Yes, I have set it up that way.

Comment: As mentioned in original post, I'm using certificates for authentication, which is what MS suggests to do.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this to happen.

In your SQL Server Management Studio, if you see a White bubble next to the server instance name, instead of the Green bubble, then you can try the following:

- "Allow an app through firewall" and add "Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" for Windows Server 2012. If it is Windows Server 2008, you can allow "Remote Administration" through firewall.

Answer (score -2):

Is it meant to be a semi colon?

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDBName SET PARTNER = 'TCP://1.2.3.4;5022'
```

The semi colon is used when connecting to IP / Port when using management studio.

Comment: The semicolon is invalid syntax for that command. "ALTER DATABASE command failed due to an invalid server connection string." The colon is correct, and that's how MS documents to do it. In fact the statement works successfully on the Mirror, just not on the principal. They're both MSSQL 2012.

Comment: Ah ok, apologies. Thought it might be worth a try as thats how SSMS connections to IP/port work. Best of luck resolving the issue.